# Spring JPA - concurrent access

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I manage to handle concurrent persistance by doing using **@version** on one property of my entity. Then I am catching an **ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException** exception.

```
@Version
@Column(name = "optlock", columnDefinition = "integer DEFAULT 0", nullable = false)
private long version = 0L;
```

I would like to go further.
Is it possible with Spring JPA, when a user reads an entity, to know if someone else is currently reading the same entity?
Thank you

Comment: If that's only requirement, I could do it java itself using ReentrantReadWriteLock. getReadLockCount()

Comment: either you need to use pessimistic lock strategy or you can retry on  ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException exception

Comment: my use case is : a user reads an entity to display it on web browser (it's a webapp), another user reads the same entity while the first user is doing some changes manually. I would like the second user to be aware that another user has opened the same entity before him and currently reading it. I have tried using @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ) on JPA Repository query @Query("select ....."); But no exception is raised when second user reads the same entity.